# Monitor Network Bandwidth with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming

I’m trying to build a python command-line program that monitors all available network interfaces in a machine. Similar to the popular (nload) which monitors the network bandwidth per interface, and (nethogs) commands which monitor network bandwidth per process I want to build a program that combine both options and also produce colored output.

### nload

[image: nload]

### nethogs

[image: nethogs]

My question is, how can I interact directly with the network interface from within python code? Is there a way to identity incoming/outgoing bandwidth speed? Is there a specific library that is recommended?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap

Comment: Thanks. However, there are similar libraries out there pcapy being one of them. What makes pypcap better. Can you shed some light on this matter

Comment: nethogs uses libpcap so I imagine you can get the same kind of functionality using it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is highly OS depended. You will need other ways to access the interface statistics on different operating systems.

From your screenshot I guess that you might want to use Linux. In that case collecting the data from `/sys/class/net/`, `/proc/net/`, `/proc/[pid]/net` and `/proc/sys/net` would be a good start. There are tons of value to make statistics from.

For the terminal output you should have a look at [curses](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html).

Comment: You're absolutely right! Sorry I didn't clarify that in my question. I'm targeting unix-like machines (Linux and OSX).  The paths you provided maybe valid for Linux systems but they are not available on OSX. Do you have any idea where I can locate the same on OSX? I also should note that I'm using the Urwid terminal interface library. It's a clean API that sits on top of ncurses for building terminal interfaces.

Comment: On MacOS you have to use sysctl - somehow. I imaging a OS X experienced developer can tell you more…